# converting activemq msg in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

I am using spring boot to decode the jms message

configuration

```
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message
    // converter
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setMessageConverter(this.jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
    // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
    return factory;
}

@Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);

    converter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
    return converter;
}
```

and I am able to receive the message, and decode the message

```
@JmsListener(destination = "myQueue", containerFactory = "myFactory")
public void receiveMessage(ActiveMQTextMessage msg) throws JMSException, IOException {

    String text = msg.getText();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MyObject obj = mapper.readValue(text, MyObject.class);
```

my problem is I don't want to call mapper.readValue(xxx) everytime, I prefer 
to configure the mapper and conversion in the messageconverter bean, I the key 
is to call the msg.getText() from the converter, but how do I get a reference of 
of the msg in the converter, or there are smarter way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Spring do that for you since you have configured the `MessageConverter` of the `factory` by `factory.setMessageConverter(this.jacksonJmsMessageConverter());`

so use the argument like this :

```
@JmsListener(destination = "myQueue", containerFactory = "myFactory")
public void receiveMessage(MyObject obj) throws JMSException, IOException {
    //do stuff with obj
}
```